# Framework7 android theme navbar padding?

Tags: android, html, html-framework-7

I am having an annoying little issue, on the framework7 website, it says if you are using the android theme for your application, then when using the navbar, you must use the with-subnavbar class on your required page, in order to add the padding necessary in order to not have everything appear behind the navbar.

The below code, is exactly what I am using, and I just can't seem to get anything appear without first being behind the damn menu!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags-->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <!-- Your app title -->
      <title>My App</title>
      <!-- Path to Framework7 iOS CSS theme styles-->
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.ios.min.css">-->
      <!-- Path to Framework7 iOS related color styles -->
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">-->
      <!-- Path to your custom app styles-->
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">-->
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Status bar overlay for full screen mode (PhoneGap) -->
      <div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>
      <!-- Panels overlay-->
      <div class="panel-overlay"></div>
      <!-- Left panel with reveal effect-->
      <div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">
         <div class="content-block">
            <p>Left panel content goes here</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Views -->
      <div class="views">
      <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
      <div class="view view-main">
      <!-- Top Navbar-->
      <div class="navbar">
         <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="left">
               <a href="#" class="link icon-only open-panel"><i class="icon icon-bars"></i></a>
            </div>
            <!-- We need cool sliding animation on title element, so we have additional "sliding" class -->
            <div class="center sliding">Dashboard</div>
            <div class="subnavbar">
               <!-- Sub navbar content, for example tabs buttons -->
               <div class="buttons-row">
                  <a href="#tab1" class="button active">Tab 1</a>
                  <a href="#tab2" class="button">Tab 2</a>
                  <a href="#tab3" class="button">Tab 3</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Pages container, because we use fixed-through navbar and toolbar, it has additional appropriate classes-->
      <div class="pages navbar-through">
         <!-- Pag has additional "with-subnavbar" class -->
         <div data-page="home" class="page with-subnavbar">
            <div class="page-content hide-bars-on-scroll">
               <div class="tabs">
                  <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
                     <div class="content-block">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>
                        <p>In sed augue non ...</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                     <div class="content-block">
                        <p>Donec iaculis ...</p>
                        <p>Curabitur egestas, mi ...</p>
                        <p>Donec iaculis posuere ...</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab3" class="tab">
                     <div class="content-block">
                        <p>Etiam non interdum erat...</p>
                        <p>Duis ac semper risus. Suspendisse...</p>
                        <p>Etiam non interdum erat...</p>
                        <p>Duis ac semper risus. Suspendisse...</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/framework7/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         (function () {
           if (Framework7.prototype.device.android) {
                 Dom7('head').append(
                     //'<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.ios.min.css">' +
                     //'<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">' +
                     '<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.material.min.css">' +
                     '<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.material.colors.min.css">' +
                     '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">'
                 );
             }
             else {
                 Dom7('head').append(
                     '<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.material.min.css">' +
                     '<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.material.colors.min.css">' +
                     //'<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.ios.min.css">' +
                     //'<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">' +
                     '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">'
                 );
             }
         })();
      </script>
      <!-- Path to your app js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
:
COPY TO CLIPBOARD    SELECT ALL
```

Comment: I has added .page-content to the component and applies a padding-top relative to toolbar's height